# Como imprimir uma string em C?

Tags: c, c++, loop

Estou estudando C e quero fazer um algoritmo que leia o nome de 30 alunos de uma turma e retorne a maior nota, menor nota e o nome desses alunos. Eu já pesquisei muito e ainda não consigo colocar o nome dos alunos com a maior e menor nota. Meu código até agora está assim (com erro):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
char aluno[21],Maluno[21], maluno[21];
float nota, maiorNota=0, menorNota=10;
int i;

for(i=0; i<30; i++){
printf("Insira o nome do(a) aluno(a) %d:\n", i+1);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", aluno);

printf("Insira a nota do(a) aluno(a) %s:\n", aluno);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", & nota);

if(nota>=0 && nota <=10){

if(maiorNota<nota){
    maiorNota = nota;
    Maluno = aluno;
}

if(menorNota>nota){
    menorNota = nota;
    maluno = aluno;
}
}
}
printf("Aluno com a menor nota e o: %s\n que tirou%f\n" ,maluno,menorNota );
printf("Aluno com a maior nota e o: %s\n que tirou%f\n" ,Maluno,maiorNota );
}
```

Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de `string` você não consegue passar de uma variável pra outra desse jeito:

```
maluno = aluno;
```

Você precisa da função `strcpy` da biblioteca `<string.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char aluno[21], Maluno[21], maluno[21];
    float nota, maiorNota = 0, menorNota = 10;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {

        printf("Insira o nome do(a) aluno(a) %d:\n", i + 1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%20s", aluno);

        printf("Insira a nota do(a) aluno(a) %s:\n", aluno);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f", &nota);

        if (nota >= 0 && nota <= 10)
        {

            if (maiorNota < nota)
            {
                maiorNota = nota;
                strcpy(Maluno, aluno);
            }

            if (menorNota > nota)
            {
                menorNota = nota;
                strcpy(maluno, aluno);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Aluno com a menor nota e o: %s\n que tirou %f\n", maluno, menorNota);
    printf("Aluno com a maior nota e o: %s\n que tirou %f\n", Maluno, maiorNota);

    return 0;
}
```

Pra mais infoemações sobre a função você pode dar uma olhada [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

Comment: Usei essa função da biblioteca de string mas continua dando erro. Não faço ideia o que estou fazendo errado

Comment: if(maiorNota<nota){
  maiorNota = nota;
  strcpy(maioraluno,aluno);
 }
 
 if(menorNota>nota){
  menorNota = nota;
  strcpy(menoraluno,aluno);

Comment: @Jackgba ajeitei a resposta, tinha esquecido a parte do caractere delimitador

Comment: O `scanf()`já põe o `'\0'` na string. Não é necessário fazê-lo antes, mas é conveniente limitar o scanf para evitar *buffer overflow*: `scanf("%20s", aluno);`